# Error Handling URLS that do not exist

Tags: asp.net

I'm having problems with handling URLS that do not exist...

In my development environment, I navigated to http://localhost:XXXX/FakeLocation and would catch the HttpException and handle it properly.

When I deployed to my production location, I'm getting a 404 error when I navigate to http://MyProductionURL/FakeLocation.  How can I make the production location throw the HttpException so my code can handle it similar to how it works in my development environment?

Comment: Can you tell us what you are using to host on production and dev? From your description I'd guess it's  visual studio's built-in web server on dev and IIS (what version?) in live. Can you confirm or correct me?

Comment: You are correct.  Prod is IIS 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to configure IIS on the production location. The easiest thing you can probably do is

1. Go to the Control Panel, and under Administrative Tools open Internet Information Services (IIS).
2. Right-click on your web site to bring up the properties.
3. Go to the Custom Errors tab
4. Select to the 404 error and edit properties on it.
5. Change the Message Type to URL.
6. Set the URL to the page you want them redirected to.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET will only handle file extensions it is registered in IIS to handle. So if the page was foo.aspx, then by default, ASP.NET returns the 404 page as set in the web.config.  And by default 404 for foo.xyz will be handled by IIS because IIS handles anything that doesn't have a mapping.

This page shows how to [set up wildcard mapping](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/03/04/tip-trick-integrating-asp-net-security-with-classic-asp-and-non-asp-net-urls.aspx) so that all requests, regardless to extension are handled by asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in the custom errors node of the web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm"
                  mode="RemoteOnly">
      <error statusCode="500"
             redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

[Msdn Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like IIS handle this exception and does not pass error to ASP.NET. 
Please check http://www.chat11.com/How_To_Setup_A_Custom_404_Error_Handler_In_.NET

Comment: That link doesn't work, but I'm guessing it's going to list pretty much the same steps I did above.

Comment: Link corrected. It contain info quite similar to your answer.